# Distance (with direction) between android devices using Sensor

Tags: android, accelerometer, physics, android-sensors, magnetometer

I'm working on a school project, here's the point : the android application, installed on 2 phones (let's call them phone A and phone B), can be use by a phone A to locate phone B. phone A sends an SMS to phone B, and phone B automatically replied with needed informations.

We must use geomagnetic and/or gravity coordinates to determine the distance and direction between phone A and phone B.

I've successfully retrieved these coordinates with the appropriate sensors, (each one in a 3 dimension float array for X, Y and Z), but I really don't know how to proceed to determine distance and direction...

If think the idea would be to create a compass but pointing at phone B instead of north, but maybe I'm completely wrong.

If anyone have an idea of how to proceed, it would be very helpful.

Comment: can you use Android's Location API? (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/package-summary.html)

Comment: No, as specified, we MUST use the 2 given sensors.

Comment: `gravity coordinates` you mean accelerometer values? These are not going to tell you anything about physical location, unless you start recording while the devices are touching, then use some advanced mathematics to calculate the final position.

Comment: Your best bet here is going to be using GPS, and calculating the coordinal distance between the two devices.

Comment: Yes I mean accelerometer values. I'm also using GPS but it's not enough accurate. I would like to be able to find a phone in a house for example.

Comment: Using these two sensors, either A, impossible, or B, requires a [Doctorate in Physics](http://www.chrobotics.com/library/accel-position-velocity). "In summary, it is possible to use the accelerometers to estimate velocity and position, but the accuracy will be very poor so that in most cases, the estimates are not useful."

Comment: See [this GoogleTechTalk](https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k?t=1235) on the subject.

Comment: You can not find one's location with accellerometer without initial position. And you will need gnss or user input for initial position.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I didn't say it but, at first, phone B sends its GPS location to phone A, so I have the GPS location of the phone B, it's just not accurate enough, maybe this can help ?

Comment: You still do not know the initial position of Device A, in the world, or even relative to B.

Comment: But I can find it using GPS, as I do for device B. It's just that I must use acceleremeter/magnetic field to find the precise location of the device

Comment: Sounds like an impossible or a misunderstood assignment.